# Unable to do a partial screen recording on OSX with quicktime

Tags: display, screen-capture, quicktime

I am using multi-screen: I am using the primary screen of my MBP plus two external monitors via displayport

When I start the screen recording, it is the message I see on my screen

[image]

I go on to select an area for recording

[image]

It is where I get stuck: there is simply no way I can start the recording after the selection. I clicked, tried to access the Quicktime app, tried some key combination. But nothing will get the recording to start.

How can I start a the screen recording for part of the screen?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. The "Start Recording" button just does not show up. I'm also using multiple monitors. It seems that this problem is related to multiple monitors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can record a selected area of your screen as follows:

- Open the `Quicktime Player` app
- Choose `File` -> `New Screen Recording` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>
- Now select the area you want to record
- Press the button in the middle of you selected area that states: `Start recording`
- To stop, there will be a squared stop button that appears in the menu bar

*As your screenshot is missing this button, you might want te restart `Quicktime Player` or reboot your machine.*

[image: Start Screen Recording]

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you drag the square, a button should appear in the centre of that area.
Click to Start.

[image]

To Stop, there will be a button that appears in the menu bar  [image]

Comment: And you just beat me to it. :)

Comment: :-) almost a photo-finish

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, it was caused by trying to drag the quicktime window between spaces. Instead, it needs to be re-assigned via the dock icon (Right Click -> Options -> Assign to This Desktop).